# Remove first three characters using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am having a data which i read in python. In a column 'title', few of the rows have extra characters like 'new' which i want to remove. i tried to find proper code but i couldnt find any, when i tried my own i got error.could anyone please help!!! Thanks in advance.
[title data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jv7j.png)

```
if indeed['title'] == indeed.loc[indeed['title'].str.startswith('new')].copy():
    indeed['title'].str[3:]
```

error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-486b16b22bea> in <module>
----> 1 if indeed['title'] == indeed.loc[indeed['title'].str.startswith('new')].copy():
      2     indeed['title'].str[3:]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1325     def __nonzero__(self):
   1326         raise ValueError(
-> 1327             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1328             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1329         )

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker thank you so much for your help this worked.

Comment: The linked duplicate has better options `indeed['title'] = indeed['title'].str.extract('(?:new)?(.*)', expand=False)` or `indeed['title'] = indeed['title'].str.replace('^new', '', regex=True)` likewise, the answer you accepted also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm understanding correctly, i read the column and search for the first 3 characters =='new', if matched, return the column without those first 3 characters in string, else return the column as is.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mydata = pd.DataFrame(['software developer','newgis developer','javascript developer','newhr partner'])
mydata.columns=['title']
mydata['newcol']=np.where(mydata['title'].str[:3]=='new', mydata['title'].str[3:], mydata['title'])

print(mydata)  
                  title                newcol
0    software developer    software developer
1      newgis developer         gis developer
2  javascript developer  javascript developer
3         newhr partner            hr partner
```

Comment: This does in fact do that, but it's a lot less efficient than just using the library

Comment: Henry Ecker version more efficient

Comment: @ifly6 Thank you so much for helping me. both the methods worked perfectly fine